# Is it possible for the mouse to influence the cursor?

Tags: windows-7, mouse, cursor

A user i just visited had a cursor that was weirdly distorted - it looked like someone merged the standard cursor with the text marking "I" cursor.

Someone said i should have tried swapping the mouse. Is it even possible for the mouse (in this case, a completely normal logitech USB office mouse) to have such an influence on the cursor? I guess it could be an issue in the mouse driver? Please enlight me, i dont know much about mouses. The system in question here is Windows Server 2008 (XenApp), and the user has no permissions to access the mouse settings in any way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mouse cursor is just a graphic that is being moved around by the drivers. Changing the mouse will not fix this issue.

The problem here is that the graphic stored in cache got corrupted. This is often fixed by a reboot and happens only rarely. If this keeps coming back, then the graphics drivers may be corrupt, but other graphics such as desktop icons etc should also become garbled at some point.

Given that you mention it is a terminal server, it may also work if the user just logs out and logs back in. Do note, disconnecting the session and reconnecting is not logging out. The session itself has to be killed entirely.

Comment: The user has this problem a lot, and according to them, it only occurs after a long time being logged in, and logging out and back in fixes it. Its the only known user that this happens to, which is rather weird...

Comment: Weird things happen when users remain logged in, especially if they do resource heavy stuff such as browsing chrome with many tabs open.